# Create a variable that indicates the source of the data with R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to create a variable that indicates in which dataframe an observation is located (identified with the variable "code").

I have this database:

```
  id code var1 var2 var9
1  1    a    3    5    4
2  2    b    4   54 5435
3  3    c   44    5    5
4  4    d    5    5   54
5  5    e    6    5    6
6  6    f    6    5    6
```

And these dataframes:

```
df1
  code var2 var3
1    a   23    4
2    e   45    6
3    k   56   98
```

```
df2
  code var2 var3
1    b  324 4343
2    z   34  545
3    q  545    6
4    j   77   67
```

```
df3
  code var2 var3
1    c    1    1
2    l   78   56
```

```
df4
  code var2 var3
1    d    2    2
2    j    1    1
```

```
df5
  code var2 var3
1    f 5335  343
```

My expected result:

```
id  code    var1    var2    var9    source
 1     a       3       5       4       df1
 2     b       4      54    5435       df2
 3     c      44       5       5       df3
 4     d       5       5      54       df4
 5     e       6       5       6       df1
 6     f       6       5       6       df5
```

---

###### Data

```r
df  <- structure(list(id = 1:6, code = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), var1 = c(3L, 4L, 44L, 5L, 6L, 6L), var2 = c(5L, 54L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), var9 = c(4L, 5435L, 5L, 54L, 6L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
df1 <- structure(list(code = c("a", "e", "k"), var2 = c(23L, 45L, 56L), var3 = c(4L, 6L, 98L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
df2 <- structure(list(code = c("b", "z", "q", "j"), var2 = c(324L, 34L, 545L, 77L), var3 = c(4343L, 545L, 6L, 67L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
df3 <- structure(list(code = c("c", "l"), var2 = c(1L, 78L), var3 = c(1L, 56L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
df4 <- structure(list(code = c("d", "j"), var2 = 2:1, var3 = 2:1), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
df5 <- structure(list(code = "f", var2 = 5335L, var3 = 343L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind_rows` from `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3, df4 = df4, df5 = df5, .id = 'source')
#>    source code var2 var3
#> 1     df1    a   23    4
#> 2     df1    e   45    6
#> 3     df1    k   56   98
#> 4     df2    b  324 4343
#> 5     df2    z   34  545
#> 6     df2    q  545    6
#> 7     df2    j   77   67
#> 8     df3    c    1    1
#> 9     df3    l   78   56
#> 10    df4    d    2    2
#> 11    df4    j    1    1
#> 12    df5    f 5335  343
```

Comment: If OP's real environment is more complex (naming or number of objects) they could use `mget` and `grep` for a more flexible approach: `mget(grep("df\\d", ls(), value = T))`. `bind_rows` will default to the name of the objects in the case of an unamed list when `.id` is used.

Comment: @emilliman5 sure, you can create the list passed to `bind_rows` using `mget`, or any other way you like to create a named list. Probably best having the data frames in a list to start with, of course. This was just a simple solution to a demonstrate the concept.

Comment: @emilliman5 although of course the OPs environment might be even more complex, and not have a structured naming convention as in the question. Why not post an answer with `mget`?  I think this would be a useful addition.